Как сохранить конфигурацию контейнера?
Запустил docker-compose. Контейнер сервиса при работе выдал ошибку
No such file or directory: 'rsvg-convert'

Я зашел внутрь контейнера и поставил:
apt-get update
apt-get install librsvg2-bin

Все заработало. Но, если остановить docker-compose, и при повторном запуске - опять придется залазить вовнутрь и ставить их.
Пробовал в Dockerfile в инструкции CMD указать:
CMD apt-get update && apt-get install librsvg2-bin

Но не помогает.

CMD не выполняется при сборке образа, доабвляйте команды в раздел RUN.
